# Why don't work media-queries in jQuery?

Tags: javascript

I am trying media-queries with jQuery but not work correctly.

```
    if ((screen.width>=20) || (screen.width<300)){
        width="190"; //Adjust the width of the image
        height="170"; //Adjust the height of the image
    }
    if ((screen.width>=300) || (screen.width<350)){
        width="240"; height="200";
    }
    if ((screen.width>=351) || (screen.width<400)){
        width="280"; height="220";
    }
    if ((screen.width>=401) || (screen.width<599)){
        width="320"; height="240";
    }
    if ((screen.width>=600) || (screen.width<757)){
        width="440";  height="320";
    }
    if ((screen.width>=758) || (screen.width<899)){
        width="320"; height="240";
    }
```

The code is called when a plugin is loaded because a new content has been added. It's a single page application. The content is loaded without refresh the browser.
I need to use mediaqueries with jquery because `width` and `height` are variables of the plugin.

Any idea? Thanks

Comment: What is `screen`? Where did it come from? Did you mean `$(window).width()` and `$(window).height()`?

Comment: What's `screen`? Is `screen` a jQuery object? What's the plugin anyways?

Comment: If you are looking for mediaqueries that jQuery/Javascript can evaluate, use the mq() method of the Modernizr plugin: http://modernizr.com/docs/#mq

Comment: What's the issue here?  What do you mean by "not work correctly"?  What are the values of `width` and `height` after these `if`s?  What plugin are you using?

Comment: @MattBall `screen` is `window.screen`, it exists in all browsers.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.screen

Comment: @RocketHazmat sure, it exists, but [that doesn't mean it's correct](http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/tableViewport.html) `:)`

Comment: I've solved it with mq of Modernizr. Thanks to @saschoar. It seems that works. Also, I think that Modernizr offers compatibility with a lot of browsers. However, Mz sometimes locks the page using local server (production).

Comment: None of what you posted has anything to do with jQuery

Answer (score 1):

Is this you wanted?

```
    if ((window.innerWidth>=20) || (window.innerWidth<300)){
        width="190"; //Adjust the width of the image
        height="170"; //Adjust the height of the image
    }
    if ((window.innerWidth>=300) || (window.innerWidth<350)){
        width="240"; height="200";
    }
    if ((window.innerWidth>=351) || (window.innerWidth<400)){
        width="280"; height="220";
    }
    if ((window.innerWidth>=401) || (window.innerWidth<599)){
        width="320"; height="240";
    }
    if ((window.innerWidth>=600) || (window.innerWidth<757)){
        width="440";  height="320";
    }
    if ((window.innerWidth>=758) || (window.innerWidth<899)){
        width="320"; height="240";
    }
```